# SSAS Tabular DAX using of IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, ssas, dax, tabular

I have this query written in SQL:

```
SELECT
   CustomerId,
   CustomerType,
   CASE WHEN CustomerStatus = 'VIP' 
        THEN CustomerDiscountType
        ELSE NULL
   END AS CustomerDiscountType
FROM Customer
```

And I would like to write this in DAX query:
I know that I can write like this:

```
EVALUATE
(
    SUMMARIZE
    (
        'Customer',
        'Customer'[CustomerId],
        'Customer'[Type],
        'Customer'[DiscountType],
        "Customer VIP", IF('Customer'[Status] = "VIP", 'Customer'[DiscountType], BLANK())
    )
)
```

But when I write if condition I need include attribute **'Customer'[DiscountType]** in that query too, but I would like to write the column name of that IF statement 
**"DiscountType"**, but it isn't possible for me like below.

```
EVALUATE
(
    SUMMARIZE
    (
        'Customer',
        'Customer'[CustomerId],
        'Customer'[Type],
        "DiscountType", IF('Customer'[Status] = "VIP", 'Customer'[DiscountType], BLANK())
    )
)
```

It failed with this error because of existing DiscountType column:
Function 'SUMMARIZE' cannot add column [DiscountType] since it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `SUMMARIZE` you can use `SELECTCOLUMNS` function. I think the error is caused because the IF function returns `DiscountType` column and it already exists in your `Customer` table. Also I am unsure if `SUMMARIZE` works without any aggregation like used in your DAX expression.

Try this expression:

```
EVALUATE
 (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Customer',
        "CustomerId", 'Customer'[CustomerId],
        "Type", 'Customer'[Type],
        "DiscountType", IF ( 'Customer'[Status] = "VIP", 'Customer'[DiscountType], BLANK () )
    )
)
```

**UPDATE:** OP tells via comments the version used is SSAS 2014 which doesn't support `SELECTCOLUMNS` function.

You can use a mix of `SUMMARIZE` and `ADDCOLUMNS` functions to get the expected result.

```
EVALUATE
 (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                DISTINCT ( Customer[CustomerID] ),
                "Type", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Customer[Type] ) ),
                "Status", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Customer[Status] ) ),
                "DiscountType1", CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Customer[DiscountType] ) )
            ),
            "DiscountType", IF ( [Status] = "VIP", [DiscountType1], BLANK () )
        ),
        [CustomerId],
        [Type],
        [DiscountType]
    )
)
```

It is not tested but should work, let me know if this helps for you.

Comment: I tried to use SELECTCOLUMNS but it failed with error Failed to resolve name 'SELECTCOLUMNS'. It is not a valid table or a function name. I have SSAS Version 2014 does it work for that version?

Comment: @Bushwacka, I've updated the answer using functions supported in 2014 version.